# Update Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to update hole matrix at each iteration.
i have tried following code:

```
  w_a1=randInitializeWeights(4,4);
  w_a2=randInitializeWeights(4,1);
  w_r1=randInitializeWeights(5,4);
  w_r2=randInitializeWeights(4,1);

  for k=1:maxstep
  wa(k+1)=wa(k);
  wb(k+1)=wb(k);
  end
```

Please help me to implement this code in matlab.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example. What do you want to achieve? What have you got so far? These questions are not clear to me from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
wa = zeros(dim);
wb = zeros(dim);

for k = 1:maxstep
    wa(k+1) = wa(k);
    wb(k+1) = wb(k)
end
```

That is if you question is how to initialise the matrices.